# How can I access to the arguments of a request like client/?sort(+name) from tornado

Tags: tornado

When, using tornado, I receive a request like **client/?sort="name"**, I can access and read those arguments by using self.request.arguments, but when using this new sort of request **client/?sort(+id)** there is no argument. how can I access to this kind of arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_argument`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_argument) will get any query string parameter by name. It takes a keyword argument for the default which, if omitted, will raise a 400 if the parameter is not present.

```
self.get_argument('sort', default='foo')
```

Comment: This would only works for request in the form ?sort="id", but I use a dgrid from Dojo, and when you press in one column's title, it makes a request in the form ?sort(+id), but when tornado get this it doesn't processed it like a regular param nor like a URI, so I can't retrieve it anyhow as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that the path is literally client/?sort(+id). That's kind of weird. But you can access it with self.request.query, although you'll have to parse it yourself.